# Invalid left-hand side expression

Tags: javascript, referenceerror

I'm trying to figure out why the bottom function I've written isn't working properly. Whenever I try to test it out, I get the following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation. I'm assuming it's because the code is failing to recognize the "x" string as being the same as the variable x once it's been stripped of it quotation marks when adding to the value of x. Can someone help me finesse this in a way to make it work? If not, can you suggest some alternate approach? Thanks in advance!

```js
var grid = [[null, null, null],
    [null, null, null],
    [null, null, null]];

 function checkWin() {

  vals = ["x", "o"];

  var x = 0;
  var o = 0;

  for (var k = 0; k < vals.length; k++) {

   var value = vals[k];

         for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

             if (grid[i][i] === value) {

              (value.replace(/['"]+/g, '')) ++;

             }

             if (grid[2 - i][i] === value) {

              (value.replace(/['"]+/g, '')) ++;

             }

             for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

                 if (grid[i][j] === value) {

                  (value.replace(/['"]+/g, '')) ++;

                 }

                 if (grid[j][i] === value) {

                  (value.replace(/['"]+/g, '')) ++;

                 }
             }
         }
     }

     if (x === 3) {
      alert("X wins!");
     } else if (o === 3) {
      alert("O wins!");
     }
    }
```

Comment: In the expression `(value.replace(/['"]+/g, '')) ++;`, after `replace` a **string** will be returned. And string cannot be incremented/decremented.

Comment: Use `parseInt()` instead of removing quotes.

Comment: Hey Tushar, I'm actually looking deeper into this to see if you might be right. I was under the impression that replace(/['"]+/g, '')  would take away the quotes. @mseifert I tried parseInt() but all I got was NaN. According to MDN the return value for parseInt() is "an integer number parsed from the given string. If the first character cannot be converted to a number, NaN is returned." Thanks anyways!

Comment: Please remove the extraneous empty lines from your code.

Comment: @Tushar Actually, it's not that a string cannot be incremented; it's that an expression cannot be incremented.

Comment: I will take a wild guess and say the problem might be an Invalid left-hand side expression.

Comment: In case you didn't get a notification that my answer below exists, take a look below.

Comment: Hey mseifert! I'm looking at it as we speak. Thanks for taking the time to respond!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following uses objects. The different grid definitions were tested

```
var grid = [
    ["o", "x", "x"],
    ["o", "x", "x"],
    ["o", "", "o"]];

var grid = [
    ["o", "x", ""],
    ["x", "x", "x"],
    ["o", "o", ""]];

var grid = [
    ["x", "x", ""],
    ["o", "x", "o"],
    ["o", "o", "x"]];

var grid = [
    ["x", "x", "o"],
    ["x", "o", "x"],
    ["o", "x", "x"]];

checkWin(grid)      

function checkWin(grid) {

var vals = [{player: "x", value: 0}, {player: "o", value: 0}];

for (var k = 0; k < vals.length; k++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        // check win by row
        vals[k].value = 0;
        // check win by col
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (grid[i][j] === vals[k].player) {
                vals[k].value++;
            }
        }
        if (vals[k].value === 3) {
            alert(vals[k].player + " wins by row " + (i+1));
            return vals[k].player;
        }
        // check win by col
        vals[k].value = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            // check col
            if (grid[j][i] === vals[k].player) {
                vals[k].value++;
                if (vals[k].value === 3) {
                    // break if you want to know what column won by
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (vals[k].value === 3) {
            alert(vals[k].player + " wins by col " + (i+1));
            return vals[k].player;
        }
    }
}
// check win by diag l to r
for (var k = 0; k < vals.length; k++) {
    vals[k].value = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (grid[i][i] === vals[k].player) {
            vals[k].value++;
        }
    }
    if (vals[k].value === 3) {
        alert(vals[k].player + " wins by diag left to right!");
        return vals[k].player;
    }
}   
// check win by diag r to l
for (var k = 0; k < vals.length; k++) {
    vals[k].value = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (grid[i][2-i] === vals[k].player) {
            vals[k].value++;
        }
    }
    if (vals[k].value === 3) {
        alert(vals[k].player + " wins by diag right to left!");
        return vals[k].player;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: There were a couple of small things which I cleaned up - e.g. removing `x` and `y` variables, changed 1 reference of vals[x] to `vals[k]`, fixed the object value in `{player: "x", value: 0}`, and one other fix.

Answer (score 0):

What about put your data in a object like this:

```
var _ = {
    x : 0,
    o : 0
};
```

and change the value like this:

```
_[value]++;
```

I hope this helps.